Understanding the scope and data coverage of Point in Time (PIT) snapshots in Elasticsearch
I'm working with Elasticsearch and utilizing the Point in Time (PIT) feature for my queries. I understand that PIT creates a snapshot(kind of) of the data to ensure consistent results across multiple searches, but I'm unclear about the scope of this snapshot.
Does the PIT snapshot encompass the entire index, including all documents and their current state at the time the PIT is created? Or is the snapshot more limited in scope, perhaps only capturing the subset of data that's relevant to the specific search query I've performed?
I'm trying to understand how comprehensive the snapshot is in terms of data representation. Could you provide a detailed explanation of how PIT snapshots work in Elasticsearch, particularly in terms of their data coverage?
Thanks!
